# Difference between joins, includes and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I just started using rails. Loving it so far, but there's a few things I haven't grasped yet.

One of them is the interaction between `joins/includes` and associations. For every model you define its relation (`has_many`, `belongs_to`, etc) to other models. And that's enough to make them connect to and find each other by primary keys, right?

So what's the point of using `joins/includes` then? My own guess is to reduce sql queries and only fetch the necessary objects, but I'd like to be clear about this.
Is associations to joins like scope is to `order/where` etc. Kind of a default behavior that is modifiable?

Would really like to have this straightened out.

Answer (score 0):

[Railscast #181 By Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins) covers this very well.

Effectively a `join` is used to join two tables efficiently on the database server. However, by default, only the columns from the first table are included in the dataset. You would use a `join` to test records in the first table against criteria in the second table.

An `include` is similar to a join, but does an efficient data retrieval on the second table's rows for any records that are relevant, and populates the Rails `ActiveRecord` cache with those records.

So, if you have a `User` class and a `Role` class, where a `User` can have a single `Role` attached to it, then both the user and role instances will be retrieved from the database at the same time.

**User #5 => points to => Role #7**

**User #10 => points to => Role #12**

Retrieving user #5 and #10 from the User table using an `includes()` will also instantiate roles #7 and #12 using an SQL query such as:

`SELECT roles.* FROM roles WHERE id IN (7,12)`